# Weird behaviour starting explorer.exe

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I have the following code:

```
from subprocess import call
import time

call('taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F', shell=True)

time.sleep(2)

call(["start", "explorer.exe"],shell=True)
```

When i run it, explorer.exe (Taskbar, environment etc.) closes, but on `call` function, it starts the `Windows Explorer` - File explorer.

If i close the explorer.exe (Let's say, from task manager) and then on cmd `start explorer.exe` it works as intended. 
Presumably, the code above does the same, but the results are not.

What is going on under the hood?

Comment: works fine on windows 10. Taskbar disappears, then reappears...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Weird, i am running windows 10 as well.

Comment: can you replace the last line by `call("explorer.exe")` ? your script won't end, but maybe you'll see a difference.

Comment: Is Python running elevated? If Explorer is started elevated, it registers a task named "\CreateExplorerShellUnelevatedTask" that reloads Explorer without elevation. Maybe something is wrong there. Kill Explorer and try running it from an elevated command prompt.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, no difference sighted.

Comment: @eryksun what do you mean by "elevated"? Administrator Rights?

Comment: I must admit It is puzzling.

Comment: Yes, with administrator rights, but elevated also means the process [mandatory integrity control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb648648) level is elevated to high. Non-elevated defaults to medium integrity level. When you "run as administrator", the shell uses the appinfo service to launch a program elevated.

Answer (score 0):

Was having trouble with this.

Turns out it's related to opening explorer.exe from a 32-bit process. Running your module from a 64-bit instance of Python should give the desired behavior.

This post led me to this conclusion: [Restarting explorer.exe only opens an explorer window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954041/restarting-explorer-exe-only-opens-an-explorer-window)